# no certificate found in safari

Tags: ssl, certificate, safari

I have a problem where our certificate is not visible (I'll get to more details after explaining the problem), in Safari. I get it working on Chrome and Firefox. The OS I am using for testing is OS X (10.10.5 Yosemite) on a mac book pro.

Basically when I try to go to the page which require the certificate it pops up a window where it asks me to select a certificate but that window is empty. In the console it says:

```
    Failed to load resource: The server "www.my.server.com" requires a client certificate.
```

I have the certificates installed in key-store and in chrome I have that same window/popup but populated by the certificate for the page.

I am thinking that it might be that the root-certificate is using ´www´ while the client certificate is not, could that be it?

Our client certificates are on the form user@my.server.com so I am only guessing that it could be a problem when Safari is looking for a certificate for www.my.server.com.

I am by no means an expert on this so I am not really sure what information I need to provide and most of the time our users are happy to get it working in chrome or firefox but I would like to understand what it is that is happening, and why I can't get it working on Safari.

Comment: What operating system?  I presume OS X based on some keywords but the OS should be explicitly stated.

Comment: Of course that is a good question to answer. I edited the question to include that information (Yosemite 10.10.5) on a macbook pro.

Comment: How did you get the client certificate, and its associated private key, onto the Mac? Did you import it into the keychain for this user? Does it show up in the "**My** Certificates" list in Keychain Access for this user?

Comment: I actually have tried a couple of different strategies, one as you say by importing in Keychain access, when doing so it does show up in my certificates. I also tried to install it under system. When doing any of those it works for Chrome. To install it for firefox I had to make use of firefox own settings.

I suspect that safari has more strict rules or something than e.g. chrome verifying the certificate. It looks like Safari doesn't find any certificate for the server.